# Can I use the OR operator or AND operator between two if..else statement?

Tags: if-statement, basic

Can/Should I use the OR operator or AND operator between two if..else statement?

```
If [statement]

end if

OR

If [statement]

end if
```

Comment: no, not that way. what kind of semantics do you want from this construct?

Comment: is this *Visual Basic*? And what has this to do with *functional programming* - btw: no you most-likely cannot do this (does not make sense in most cases) - you probably want `if ... then ... else if ... ` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them into one statement like this:

```
if age < 30 AND height_feet > 6.1 then
    ' do something
else
    ' do something else
end if
```

If you have to check the OR condition, just switch the AND to OR.

EDIT

You can combine if statements like this also:

```
if age < 30 AND height_feet > 6.1 then
    ' do something
else if age < 30 OR height_feet > 6.1 then
    ' do something
else
    if employee_type = 1 then 
        ' do something
    else
        ' do something
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Can I do this: if age < 30 AND height_feet > 6.1 then
    ' do something
else
  if x<1  ' do something else
end if end if

Comment: Yes. I've added an example of that. Depending on your language, the if..then construct may look different.